# rviz publish camera

Tags: ros, rviz, sensor-msgs, sensor-msgs#image, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rviz to visualise the images from a camera [sensor_msgs/Image] and some markers [visualization_msgs/Marker] and grids. That's working fine and gives me exactly the view I want to have.

Now I would like to have this camerastream with markers published as one [sensor_msgs/Image]. This is going to be transmitted to an Android tablet, so I want all the information compressed in just a camerastream.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59554/rviz-publish-camera/) by [noe_vb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4546/noe_vb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have ros running on your tablet, you could run rviz from your tablet and subscribe to the appropriate topics.  (Assuming you don't need it on the robot if you have a tablet).

That would probably be the easiest way in theory (tablets can be a pain).

If you just want the video for presentation I suggest using a screen capture and just grabbing the stream and sending it to a video file.

---

Originally posted by [BlackManta](https://answers.ros.org/users/428/blackmanta/) with karma: 56 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-06**:
rviz is a visualization tool it is not designed to publish anything.